# Subtracting two values in ng-model for input type

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using a ng-model for an input type of number which works fine after some operation i would like to subtract the original value in the input and show the new value in the model which i want to do in the html itself.So is it possible to do it in ng-model.I will be using the same model for input also.

```
<label class="item item-input InputFormFull" ng-if="vm.product.selectedtype === 'piece'">
      <span class="input-label"> {{'loadcount_message' | translate}} *</span>
      <input stopccp decimalpoint ng-model="vm.product.count" maxlength="8" placeholder="0" type="number" ng-change="vm.onTotalCost()" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); this.value = this.value.replace(/(\..*)\./g, 0);" ng-click= "vm.hideScrollContent()"
      />
    </label>
```

Eg:

the value in the input is 5000 means if another input has the value as 500 means then these should be subtracted and the new value of 4500 should be displayed in the place of 5000.

Comment: Where is your subtraction?

Comment: *"I want to do it in the html"* . Why? Business logic doesn't belong in the html